# How to use Angular Templating or Routing without controllers?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, angularjs

Is it possible to used the angular templating or routing without using angular controllers?

I have worked on angular a few months ago but things happened and still on a website that is not angular.

In short i forgot if it is possible to use angular in loading the header, footer sidebar and menu and content.

But the processings of each content will be done in jquery / i mean main stuffs.

for example i load the index.php or html

it will load the
header
the foolter
the navigation
then the content

when it doms ready ( jquery )
the jquery ajax will execute and load json from an api and populate my 
datatable.

BUT.. not sure if this is workable since i STOPPED working with angular..

Comment: Why don't you simply start working with Angular and simply try it for yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea, that can work. Just use something like:

```
.config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/home", {
        templateUrl: "app/views/home.php"
    }).when("/page1", {
        templateUrl: "app/views/page1.php"
    });
}])
```

Basically, leave out the controllers if you don't want to use them.

Just make sure you place your `<ng-view></ng-view>` where the content is supposed to go.

Comment: tnx i think this is what im looking for.. I got my head all setup with controllers.. it made me un decisive :( tnx tnx